# Android Studio занимает много места на диске

Tags: android-studio

**Android Studio** занимает много места на жёстком диске, каждый раз что-то подкачивает и так далее. Свободная память с 15 ГБ утекла до 4 ГБ.

Поменял место загрузки **gradle** — не помогло.

Не подскажете, как это можно исправить?

[image: локальный диск]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: "Не подскажите как это можно исправить?" Установить больше памяти или удалить что-то с диска

Comment: Вторая картинка здесь зачем?

Comment: Чтобы вспоминалось что такое "AndroidStudio"

Comment: Может, эмуляторов наставил много?

Answer (score 1):

Так и должно быть. AndroidStudio всегда занимает очень много памяти, это одна из её особенностей. Больше всего занимают эмуляторы, дополнения (в том числе различные версии Sdk), образы систем.

Как с этим справиться? Есть два способа:

1. Почистить лишние дополнения, оставить только те, что реально нужны (например, только одно конкретное API и соответствующее ему Sdk). То же с эмуляторами.
2. (Рекомендуемый) Смириться с этим и заранее выделить под AndroidStudio как можно больше места, особенно если планируете заниматься разработкой на Android профессионально.